# List all CouchApps in a CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, couchapp, couchrest

Is there a way to list all CouchApps in one CouchDB?

I would like to do something like:

```
couchapp list http://domain.tld:5984/content
```

And get back a list of all couchapp names.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "couchapp" here? Databases? Design documents?

Comment: CouchApps are JavaScript and HTML5 applications served directly from CouchDB. http://couchapp.org

Comment: Yes, I know what a CouchApp is. But what I meant was: "What do you want to list?. Databases or design documents (within databases)?".

Comment: I want to list all couchapp that I have in that database. So the database is called content and I have a cuple of apps within it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use the _all_docs and then select the ones that you are interested in out of that list with the startkey and endkey.

Since all design documents _id starts with _design/ we can select all docs between _design/ and the following character which is 0, giving _design0.

```
http://www.couch.db:5984/database/_all_docs?startkey="_design/"&endkey="_design0"
```

Best of luck!